# How can I make array of bowlers?

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor

Following is the question which I am trying to solve-

In a one day international, the bowling figures of all the bowlers have been provided. The objective is to create an array of Bowler and return it. Note that the objects should appear in the same order in the array as they appear in the input.
The input is provided a string. The string has space demarcated details of each bowler provided as Name-Overs-Maiden-Runs-Wickets, like , “Zaheer-10-1-55-0 Harbhajan-8.4-0-44-2 Ishant-10-0-71-1″.Define a function that takes and prints the array of Bowler returned.

There is some error in the code but I am unable to detect it.

```
public class MakeArrayOfBowlers{

    String name;
    double over;
    int maiden;
    int runs;
    int wickets;


    public MakeArrayOfBowlers(String input){
        String[] str=input.split("-");
        this.name=str[0];
        this.over=Double.parseDouble(str[1]);
        this.maiden=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
        this.runs=Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
        this.wickets=Integer.parseInt(str[4]);
    }

    public MakeArrayOfBowlers[] makeBowlers (String  input){  
        MakeArrayOfBowlers str= (MakeArrayOfBowlers) new MakeArrayOfBowlers("Zaheer-10-1-55-0 Harbhajan-8.4-0-44-2 Ishant-10-0-71-1");
        String[] str1 = input.split(" ");
        MakeArrayOfBowlers bowler[]= new MakeArrayOfBowlers[str1.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){           
            bowler = new MakeArrayOfBowlers[str1.length];
            MakeArrayOfBowlers obj = new MakeArrayOfBowlers(str1[i]);
            bowler[i] = obj;
        }
        return bowler;


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is an error in the code?  What is it doing incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I m not getting any output with this code.Either I have given input wrongly or something else.

Comment: How are you calling it?  Where's your `main`?

Comment: This is all what I have.Is anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a own class bowler (constructor should be better but its your example ;)):

```
public class Bowler {
private String name;
private double over;
private int maiden;
private int runs;
private  int wickets;   

public Bowler(String input){
    String[] str=input.split("-");
    this.name=str[0];
    this.over=Double.parseDouble(str[1]);
    this.maiden=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
    this.runs=Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
    this.wickets=Integer.parseInt(str[4]);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public double getOver() {
    return over;
}


public int getMaiden() {
    return maiden;
}


public int getRuns() {
    return runs;
}


public int getWickets() {
    return wickets;
}
}
```

Than split your string and add it for every bowler:

```
public class MakeArrayOfBowlers {

public static Bowler[] makeBowlers(String input) {
    String[] splitArray = input.split(" ");

    Bowler[] bowler = new Bowler[splitArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
        bowler[i] = new Bowler(splitArray[i]);
    }
    return bowler;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bowler[] bowlers = makeBowlers("Zaheer-10-1-55-0 Harbhajan-8.4-0-44-2 Ishant-10-0-71-1");
    for (Bowler bowler : bowlers) {
        System.out.println(bowler.getName()+"-"+bowler.getOver()+"-"+bowler.getMaiden()+"-"+bowler.getRuns()+"-"+bowler.getWickets());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Your code worked but it is not giving the right output.The output should be array of bowlers {Zaheer-10-1-55-0, Harbhajan-8.4-0-44-2 ,Ishant-10-0-71-1}  And it is returning output like- Zaheer/n Harbhajan/n Ishant/n "/n is for names in different lines"

Comment: You get back a array of bowlers. You can modifiy the "view" like you want ;)

Comment: Since I am doing this topic for the first time.I have no idea how to do it.Can I get a hint that which line I have to modify.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-initializing the bowler array inside the for-loop. Try removing that line (the first line inside your loop).

Comment: Tried removing.No improvement

Answer (score 0):

```
public MakeArrayOfBowlers[] makeBowlers (String  input){  
    String[] str1 = input.split(" ");
    MakeArrayOfBowlers bowlers[]= new MakeArrayOfBowlers[str1.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){ 
      MakeArrayOfBowler bowler = new MakeArrayOfBowlers(str1[i]);
      bowlers[i] = obj;
    }
    return bowlers;
  }
```

From your main function call

```
MakeArrayOfBowlers o = new MakeArrayOfBowlers();
MakeArrayOfBowlers[] b = o.makeBowlers("Zaheer-10-1-55-0 Harbhajan-8.4-0-44-2 Ishant-10-0-71-1");
```

Comment: Does this compile?  I don't see the declaration of `obj`.